# Using a list of search patterns in LIKE or IN expression

Tags: postgresql, search, sql-like

The question: I have a list of sales quotations and many of them are not valid as they are simply in the system for practice or training.  Usually the quotation name contains the word 'Test' or 'Dummy'.  (In a couple of instances the quote_name contains 'Prova' - which happens to be Italian for 'Test').

Given that I cannot easily control the list of strings to search for, I decided to maintain the list in a second table - 'Terms to Search for'.  A simple one column table with a list of terms ('Test', 'Prova', 'Dummy', ...).

In Amazon Redshift, I tried a simple CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(vx.quote_name) LIKE ('%' + UPPER(terms.term) + '%') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Any DPS"
```

However, that seems to only get the first search term in the list.

Also, for the same quotation, which can have multiple rows due to multiple items being sold, I usually get one row set to 'Y' and the rest set to 'N'.

I modified the statement to:

```
---- #4a: get a list of the quotes whose quote_names match the patterns in the list
SELECT 
vx.master_quote_number, 
'Y' AS "Any DPS"

FROM t_quotes vx, any_dps_search_families terms

WHERE UPPER(vx.prod_fmly) IN ('%'+ UPPER(terms.term) +'%'); 

--- 4b: merge Any DPS results back in

select vx.*, dps."Any DPS"
from t_quotes vx
LEFT JOIN transform_data_4 dps ON (vx.master_quote_number = dps.master_quote_number)
```

But that isn't doing it either.

**Environment:** Amazon Redshit (which is mostly like Postgres).  An answer to this in Postgres would be ideal.  I can switch this clause to MySQL if needed but I'd rather not.

Comment: Apologies I mixed the search table name - in step 4a it was terms and in 4b I used 'dps'.  same table - transform_data_4 is the result step from 4a,  like a 'select into'.

Comment: I think Redshift is based on a very old version of Postgres.  Rather, an answer given here should be for Redshift specifically.

Comment: Please show sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for lateral joins (untested):

```
SELECT vx.master_quote_number
FROM any_dps_search_families terms
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT master_quote_number
                       FROM t_quotes
                       WHERE UPPER(prod_fmly)
                             LIKE ('%' || UPPER(terms.term) || '%')
                      ) vx;
```